# How does Java restricts Multiple inheritance?

Tags: java, multiple-inheritance

While reading about the multiple inheritance or diamond problem in Java I realized that it is not supported. But I wonder how does Java actually restricts multiple inheritance?

Is there any class to check if the programmer is passing more than one class name after extends keyword or some other way to detect this functionality?

I read few articles but nothing suggest about how exactly Java prevents Multiple inheritance except the one common answer that it throws an error: classname is inheriting multiple classes.

Comment: When you write more than 1 class after the `extends`.. isn't it just that?

Comment: More than one class name after the `extends` keyword is a compile time  error. If you can't compile a program, you can't run it. That is how Java prevents multiple inheritance.

Comment: @user3437460 Not very sure about that. Going through theoretical readings.

Answer (score 5):

> But I wonder how does Java actually restricts multiple inheritance?

It is disallowed at the syntax level.  The syntax for a class declaration allows one class name after the `extends` keyword.   And the names in the `implements` list must be interface names not class names.   See [Section 8.1 Class Declarations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1) of the JLS.  The compiler checks both of these things.  Java source code that attempts to declare multiple super-classes will not compile.

At the implementation level, the format for a ".class" file only allows one class to be listed as the `super_class`; see the `ClassFile` structure in  [Section 4.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se9/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.1) of the JVM spec.  The identifiers in the `interfaces` must all refer to interfaces.  The various classfile constraints specified in the JVM spec are enforced by the JVM's native classloader.

---

If you want to *see* how these restrictions are enforced, you can download an OpenJDK source tree and read the code for yourself.  (I don't see the point though.  All you really need to know is that the restrictions are strictly enforced and there is no practical way to get around that enforcement.)

Answer (score 2):

If you try to extend more than one class, the compiler will actually complain, and state `error: '{' expected`. If you are interested in what part of the JDK actually does this, I suggest taking a look at the [OpenJDK sources](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk10/file/b09e56145e11). Source code for the `javac` parser can be found [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk10/file/b09e56145e11/src/jdk.compiler/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javac/parser).

As a side note, Java disallows multiple inheritance of state, which is what you are referring to. You can still achieve multiple inheritance of behavior through implementing multiple interfaces, though.